# What is the purpose of the flux container function 'createFunctional'?

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am working on a project that has a flux pattern that uses the flux container function "createFunctional" like this :

```
import {Container} from 'flux/utils';
import View from './MyView.js';
import AppStore from './AppStore.js';

function getStores() {
  return [
    AppStore
  ];
}

function getState() {
  var state = {
    pie: AppStore.getState(),
  };

  return state;
}

export default Container.createFunctional(View, getStores, getState);
```

I would like to understand this code better but I am finding it hard to find documentation on this function.

I am guessing that is is somehow binding the store and state function to the view, and it is somehow the same thing as this code (which I have restructured based on the [example on the flux website](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/flux-utils.html)) :

```
class MyView extends Component {
  static getStores() {
    return [AppStore];
  }

  static calculateState(prevState) {
    return {
      pie: AppStore.getState(),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <div>blah..</div>;
  }
}

const container = Container.create(CounterContainer);
```

Comment: I haven't used pure flux before but looking into the source this seems similar to `connect` in redux. I think it watches changes in stores and when there are changes, it passes the entire state as props to the underlying component (the first parameter).

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/src/container/FluxContainer.js) it's rather simple.

It creates a container component. The component subscribes to all the given stores. When there is a change in the stores, it uses the `getState` function to grab anything of importance from them.

The result of `getState` is then stored in `this.state` of the container.

The `render` function of the container simply renders `View`, passing it the whole state (the result of `getState`) as properties.

In short, the container watches changes in the stores and passes them to the view as properties. That simplifies the design of components because they don't have to deal with state and subscription to stores.

Comment: I really recommend to check the source. It's interesting how simple the implementation of flux (or redux) is.

Comment: would you say the two bits of code i have in my question are the same thing then?

Comment: @OliverWatkins More or less, see https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/src/container/FluxContainer.js#L245, the `createFunctional` does almost the same but it is more generic. It allows you to pass additional properties and it also passes context down which probably has some importance in some context-related edge cases.